# Swapping two rows changes the sign of the determinant proof using induction

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, determinant

> Prove by induction on $n$ that if $A,B$ are $n \times n$ matrices with
>   $B$ obtained from $A$ by swapping $i^{th}$ row and $j^{th}$ row of
>   $A$, where $1 \le i < j \le n$, then $\det(B) = -\det(A)$.

Starting with the case $n = 2$ and claim obviously holds. Then suppose inductively that $n \ge 3$ and argument holds for all $n-1$. Then for $n$, we can express $\det(B)$ as

$$\det(B) = ...+(-1)^{i+1}a_{j1}\begin{vmatrix}
    a_{12} & ... & a_{1n} \\
    . &  & . \\
    a_{i2} & ... & a_{in} \\
    . &  & . \\
    a_{n2} & ... & a_{nn} \\
    \end{vmatrix} + ... +(-1)^{j+1}a_{i1}\begin{vmatrix}
    a_{12} & ... & a_{1n} \\
    . &  & . \\
    a_{j2} & ... & a_{jn} \\
    . &  & . \\
    a_{n2} & ... & a_{nn} \\
    \end{vmatrix}+...$$

Here, I have written two of the terms which either doesn't contain $a_{j2}$ row or $a_{i2}$ row. Except these two terms, other terms will include both these rows. Now, if we define $S$ to be the sum of the terms that contain both $a_{j2}$ row and $a_{i2}$ row (in other words, sum of the terms except the written ones). Then by inductive hyphothesis, when we swap $a_{j2}$ row and $a_{i2}$ row in all of these terms, their sum will be $-S$, which is sum of the terms except written ones in $\det(A)$.

After this point, in order to prove the claim, we need to show that when we multiply written terms by $(-1)$, we need to have the term
$$(-1)^{i+1}a_{i1}\begin{vmatrix}
    a_{12} & ... & a_{1n} \\
    . &  & . \\
    a_{j2} & ... & a_{jn} \\
    . &  & . \\
    a_{n2} & ... & a_{nn} \\
    \end{vmatrix} + (-1)^{j+1}a_{j1}\begin{vmatrix}
    a_{12} & ... & a_{1n} \\
    . &  & . \\
    a_{i2} & ... & a_{in} \\
    . &  & . \\
    a_{n2} & ... & a_{nn} \\
    \end{vmatrix}$$

which should imply
$$(-1)^i = (-1)^{j+1}\ and\ (-1)^j = (-1)^{i+1}$$

But when both $i$ and $j$ are even or both of them are odd, this claim is clearly false. This is the point where I am stuck. I think the problem is about $S$ and $-S$ part but I couldn't find where the things went wrong.

Any correction/help on this method is appreciated, as well as better way of induction. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Consider proving the more restrictive scenario of if $B$ is achieved from $A$ by swapping to *adjacent* rows first.  Then, using the result gained from that, generalize to the desired result by noticing how any swap of two arbitrary rows can be described by an odd number of successive swaps of adjacent rows.

Comment: This is also a great suggestion and a different approach. I will try to prove it in this way as well, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sketch of a proof, I'll leave you to fill in the details.

Let $A,B,n,i,j$ be as in your question, take any $k\ne i,j$, and calculate $\det(B)$ by expanding along row $k$.  Then
$$\eqalign{\det(B)
  &=(-1)^{k+1}b_{k1}\det(B_{k1})+(-1)^{k+2}b_{k2}\det(B_{k2})+\cdots
    (-1)^{k+n}b_{kn}\det(B_{kn})\cr
  &=(-1)^{k+1}a_{k1}(-\det(A_{k1}))+(-1)^{k+2}a_{k2}(-\det(A_{k2}))+\cdots
    (-1)^{k+n}a_{kn}(-\det(A_{kn}))\cr
  &=-\det(A)\ .\cr}$$
We have used the facts

- $b_{kj}=a_{kj}$, because row $k$ was not changed;
- $B_{kj}$ is $A_{kj}$ with two rows swapped, and these are $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrices so we can use induction, so $\det(B_{kj})=-\det(A_{kj})$.

Comment: Expanding along row $k$ is much more logical than expanding from column $1$ as I did. I think after doing what you said, I can define $S$ to be the sum of all the terms this time, and by using inductive hyphothesis, I can claim that changing the $i$ row and $j$ row back in all these terms  will yield the sum $-S$, as well as give me the expression for $\det(A)$. Thank you very much :)